# В чем причина C6385 "Чтение недопустимых данных"?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Есть код- на решение СЛАУ методом Гаусса. Он компилируется, однако выводит ошибку памяти в изначальной матрице.Хотя я ее задавал динамической и памяти должно хватить- все равно возникает ошибка компиляции. Не могу понять в чем причина перегрузки

```cpp
int main() {
    int n, j, i, k,m;
    cout.precision(4);
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout << "\nEnter the no. of equations\n";
    cin >> n;
    m = n + 1;
    double** p = new double*[n];
    for ( int count = 0; count < n; count++)
    {
        p[count] = new double[m];  

    }
    double** x = new double*[n];
    for (int count = 0; count < n; count++)
    {
        x[count] = new double[n];
    }
    cout << "\nEnter the elements:\n";
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
            cin >> p[i][j];
        }
            
    }
        
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (k = i + 1; k < n; k++) {
            if (abs(p[i][i]) < abs(p[k][i]))
                for (j = 0; j <= n; j++)
                {
                    double temp = p[i][j];
                    p[i][j] = p[k][j];
                    p[k][j] = temp;
                } 
        }
    }
    cout << "\nThe matrix after Pivotisation is:\n";
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
            cout << p[i][j] << setw(16);
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {          
        for (k = i + 1; k < n; k++)
        {
            double t = p[k][i] / p[i][i];
            for (j = 0; j <= n; j++)
                p[k][j] = p[k][j] - t * p[i][j];    
        }
    }
    cout << "\n\nThe matrix after gauss-elimination is as follows:\n";
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)            
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= n; j++)
            cout << p[i][j] << setw(16);
        cout << "\n";
    }
    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)               
    {                        
        *x[i] = p[i][n];                
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++){
            if (j!= i) {
                x[i] = x[i] - int(( p[i][j] * (*x[j])));
                *x[i] *= (1 / p[i][i]);
            }                
                
        }
                             
    }
    cout << "\nThe values of the variables are as follows:\n";
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << x[i] << endl;
    }
    delete[] p;
    delete[] x;
    return 0;
```

Проблемный кусок:

```cpp
    cout << "\nEnter the elements:\n";
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
            cin >> p[i][j];
        }
            
    }
```

Comment: впредь хоть немного времени уделяйте оформлению вопроса

Comment: Прошу извинить если как то нечетко описал проблему либо не учел все детали визуального оформления Вопрос все в том же- в указанном куске кода ошибка памяти которую я не могу разрешить

Comment: Так компиляции или выполнения?... Кстати, память вы не дочищаете...

Comment: Она компилируется, однако нужного ответа не дает. Все промежуточные матрицы выводит, но конечный ответ вообще не числовой и даже близко не является решением

Comment: Так где вы видите ошибку C6385 "Чтение недопустимых данных"? А тут - `cout << x[i] << endl;` - вы выводите **адреса**, у вас же `double**x;` объявлено...

Comment: В выделенном куске кода он говорит что "Чтение недопустимых данных из p[i] доступный обьем для чтения равен "m*8" байт однако считать можно только "16" байт"

Comment: @AdamSanners кто он?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch О чем вы?

Comment: Не знаю, чем анализатору кода это не понравилось, там вроде как все нормально... Ну, а что адреса выводите вместо значений - это уже вопрос второй.

Comment: @Harry тогда верной записью вывода будет `cout << *x[i] << endl`  если я правильно вас понял?;

Comment: Это вы выведете **первый** элемент вектора `x[i]`. Кстати, вот тут у вас еще ерунда - `x[i] = x[i] - int(( p[i][j] * (*x[j])));` Если я верно понимаю, `x` - это вектор-решение? Тогда зачем вы его делаете матрицей `nxn`?

Comment: @AdamSanners вы написали: `В выделенном куске кода он говорит что ...` - кто он?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Судя по номеру ошибки - это анализатор кода в Visual Studio

Comment: @Harry я посчитал что такое представление лучше в данной ситуации. Предполагается что решение можно будет использовать для систем со многими ЛАУ поэтому матрица проще

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch компилятор. Если вы работали с VS 2019 то возможно вы встречали тип ошибки когда он подчеркивает зеленой волнистой линией- это не мешает компилировать однако выдает ошибку впоследствии

Comment: @AdamSanners во-первых уже ответили, это анализатор, это не может быть компилятор. Во-вторых, не понятно что значит: не мешает компилировать, но выдает ошибку впоследствии - вы так варнинг называете чтоли? Но и варнинга сдесь быть не должно - вроде все порядке

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch варн однако есть. Как раз из за использования памяти в основной матрице